# Query a Barcode in django model

Tags: python, django

I have created Barcodes in my model using the following format:

```
"YNT" + str(pk).zfill(4) + str(i.item.pk).zfill(4) + str(j + 1).zfill(5)
```

where `pk` id the `GRN` ID

and it looks like the following

```
example:  YNT0103000500055
```

Now when I am scanning the barcode I want to check if the item actually exists or not for that I have done this:

```
 c = request.GET['code']
        try:
            #len(YNT) = 3
            #len(grn) = 4
            #len(product) = 4
            #len(serial) = 5
            grn = int(c[3:7])   #103
            product = int(c[7:11]) #5
            serial = int(c[11:])  #55
            print("grn", grn)
            print("grn", product)
            print("grn", serial)
            obj = Grn.objects.filter(pk=grn, items__item=product)

            print("obj.items.item_quantity", obj.items.item_quantity)

            if obj.items.item_quantity>serial:
                res = Product.objects.get(pk=product).description
```

I am able to get the object but how do I check the serial count i.e. serial is less or equal than the quantity of that product in the `GRN`

GRN Model:

```
class GrnItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)


class Grn(models.Model):

    reference_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    inward_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GrnItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this by [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) to get the sum of of `item_quantity`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
obj = Grn.objects.get(pk=grn, items__item=product)
total = obj.items.aggregate(total=Sum('item_quantity'))['total']
```

You can add the [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) like this:

```
count = obj.items.count()
```

Another optimized way to do:

```
from django.db.models import Count
obj = Grn.objects.filter(pk=grn, items__item=product).annotate(item_count=Count('items')).first()
print(obj.item_count)
```

Comment: I tried the second way but I don't need the count of `items` I need the `item_quantity` of the `obj = Grn.objects.get(pk=grn, items__item=product)`. How do I get that ?

Comment: Please check the first code snippet of the answer